# oracle sql Monthly financial report : Provide a report that shows total income of the vehicle owners for every single month

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

Monthly financial report :

Provide a report that shows total income of the vehicle owners for every single month (limit it to  one year – 12 months - and print only if there is activity in a given month)

find the trips table details below

```
    TRIP_ID C_id  V_OWNERID DISTANCE_ID  TRIP_DATE          soruce   town    luggage NO_OF_PASSENGER   amount
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1001    1009    117 29  9   11-FEB-20 11.31.54.496000000 AM Baltimore   Charlotte   1   2   TRUE    1510
    1002    1010    114 23  4   10-JAN-19 05.31.54.130000000 PM Philadelp   Pittsburgh  2   1   FALSE   1530
    1003    1002    116 31  8   27-OCT-19 01.39.47.130000000 AM Dallas      Los Angel   2   3   TRUE    9270
    1004    1005    118 25  10  27-OCT-19 01.01.04.130000000 AM Richmond    Virginia    1   4   FALSE   905
    1005    1006    113 24  2   28-OCT-19 01.01.04.130000000 AM Westchester Gettysburg  0   5   TRUE    1340
    1006    1009    115 29  7   15-MAY-19 01.01.04.130000000 AM Baltimore   Charlotte   1   1   FALSE   475
    1021    1009    117 29  9   12-FEB-20 11.31.54.496000000 AM Baltimore   Charlotte   1   2   TRUE    1510
    1022    1009    117 29  9   13-FEB-20 11.31.54.496000000 AM Baltimore   Charlotte   1   2   TRUE    1510
    1023    1009    117 29  9   14-FEB-20 11.31.54.496000000 AM Baltimore   Charlotte   1   2   TRUE    1510
    1024    1009    117 19  9   22-FEB-20 11.31.54.496000000 AM Baltimore   Frederick   1   2   TRUE    190
    1025    1009    117 19  9   23-FEB-20 11.31.54.496000000 AM Baltimore   Frederick   1   2   TRUE    190
    1042    1009    117 61  9   19-JAN-20 11.31.54.496000000 AM Baltimore   Delaware    1   2   TRUE    0
    1043    1009    117 61  9   11-JAN-20 11.31.54.496000000 AM Baltimore   Delaware    1   2   TRUE    0
    1044    1009    117 61  9   16-JAN-20 11.31.54.496000000 AM Baltimore   Delaware    1   2   TRUE    0
    1045    1009    117 61  9   26-JAN-20 11.31.54.496000000 AM Baltimore   Delaware    1   2   TRUE    0
    1046    1009    117 62  9   15-AUG-20 11.31.54.496000000 AM Baltimore   Michigan    1   2   TRUE    0
    1047    1009    117 61  9   31-AUG-20 11.31.54.496000000 AM Baltimore   Delaware    1   2   TRUE    0

desc trips;

TRIP_ID          NOT NULL NUMBER       
CUSTOMER_ID               NUMBER       
V_OWNERID           NUMBER       
DISTANCE_ID               NUMBER       
VEHICLE_ID                NUMBER       
TRIP_DATE                 TIMESTAMP(6) 
SOURCE_TOWN               VARCHAR2(20) 
DESTINATION_TOWN          VARCHAR2(20) 
LUGGAGE                   NUMBER       
NO_OF_PASSENGER           NUMBER       
HOLIDAY                   VARCHAR2(5)  
TOTAL_PAYMENT             FLOAT(126)
```

vehicle owner table

```
    VEHICLE_OWNERID   OWNER_NAME   
-------------------------------------------------              
    110               JOHN
    111                 EMMA
    112             SURESH
    113              JOSHUA
    114              Prakash
    115                 Prasad
    116              Jayawardena
    117                  Suchitra

desc VEHICLE_OWNERID   ;
    VEHICLE_OWNERID   NOT NULL NUMBER       
    OWNER_NAME                 VARCHAR2(20)
```

vehicles tables

```
 VEHICLE_ID   VEHICLE_OWNERID          MAKE    
------------------------------------------------------                       
    1   110                           Honda
    2   111                           Toyota
    3   112                          Tesla
    4   113                             Ford
    5   114                            BMW
    6   115                            AUDI
    7   116                            Fiat

VEHICLE_ID       NOT NULL NUMBER       
VEHICLE_OWNERID           NUMBER       
MAKE                      VARCHAR2(15)
```

Comment: So what is your question ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the *sum of amount per owner per month* for the last 12 months including the current month.

You can use an aggregate function as follows:

```
SELECT
    V.OWNER_NAME,
    TRUNC(T.TRIP_DATE, 'MONTH'),
    SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_BY_MONTH
FROM
    TRIPS T
    JOIN VEHICLE_OWNER V ON T.V_OWNERID = V.VEHICLE_OWNERID
WHERE
    T.TRIP_DATE >= ADD_MONTHS(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH'), 1), - 12)
GROUP BY
    V.OWNER_NAME,
    TRUNC(T.TRIP_DATE, 'MONTH')
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(select 'JAN'as month, t.vehicle_ownerid,(sum(t.total_payment))as total_income from trips t,vehicles v ,vehicle_owner vo
where 
 v.VEHICLE_ID =t.VEHICLE_ID
and vo.vehicle_ownerid =v.vehicle_ownerid  and trip_date >= date '2020-1-1' 
and trip_date <= date '2020-1-31'
group by  t.vehicle_ownerid)
union all
(select  'FEB'as month,t.vehicle_ownerid,(sum(t.total_payment))as total_income from trips t,vehicles v ,vehicle_owner vo
where 
 v.VEHICLE_ID =t.VEHICLE_ID
and vo.vehicle_ownerid =v.vehicle_ownerid  and trip_date >= date '2020-2-1' 
and trip_date <= date '2020-2-29'
group by  t.vehicle_ownerid)
union all
(select  'MAR' as month,t.vehicle_ownerid,(sum(t.total_payment))as total_income from trips t,vehicles v ,vehicle_owner vo
where 
 v.VEHICLE_ID =t.VEHICLE_ID
and vo.vehicle_ownerid =v.vehicle_ownerid  and trip_date >= date '2020-3-1' 
and trip_date <= date '2020-3-31'
group by  t.vehicle_ownerid)
union all
(select  'APR' as month,t.vehicle_ownerid,(sum(t.total_payment))as total_income from trips t,vehicles v ,vehicle_owner vo
where 
 v.VEHICLE_ID =t.VEHICLE_ID
and vo.vehicle_ownerid =v.vehicle_ownerid  and trip_date >= date '2020-4-1' 
and trip_date <= date '2020-4-30'
group by  t.vehicle_ownerid)
union all
(select  'MAY' as month,t.vehicle_ownerid,(sum(t.total_payment))as total_income from trips t,vehicles v ,vehicle_owner vo
where 
 v.VEHICLE_ID =t.VEHICLE_ID
and vo.vehicle_ownerid =v.vehicle_ownerid  and trip_date >= date '2020-5-1' 
and trip_date <= date '2020-5-31'
group by  t.vehicle_ownerid)
union all
(select  'JUN' as month,t.vehicle_ownerid,(sum(t.total_payment))as total_income from trips t,vehicles v ,vehicle_owner vo
where 
 v.VEHICLE_ID =t.VEHICLE_ID
and vo.vehicle_ownerid =v.vehicle_ownerid  and trip_date >= date '2020-6-1' 
and trip_date <= date '2020-6-30'
group by  t.vehicle_ownerid)
union all
(select  'JUL' as month,t.vehicle_ownerid,(sum(t.total_payment))as total_income from trips t,vehicles v ,vehicle_owner vo
where 
 v.VEHICLE_ID =t.VEHICLE_ID
and vo.vehicle_ownerid =v.vehicle_ownerid  and trip_date >= date '2020-7-1' 
and trip_date <= date '2020-7-31'
group by  t.vehicle_ownerid)
union all
(select  'AUG' as month,t.vehicle_ownerid,(sum(t.total_payment))as total_income from trips t,vehicles v ,vehicle_owner vo
where 
 v.VEHICLE_ID =t.VEHICLE_ID
and vo.vehicle_ownerid =v.vehicle_ownerid  and trip_date >= date '2020-8-1' 
and trip_date <= date '2020-8-31'
group by  t.vehicle_ownerid)
union all
(select  'SEP' as month,t.vehicle_ownerid,(sum(t.total_payment))as total_income from trips t,vehicles v ,vehicle_owner vo
where 
 v.VEHICLE_ID =t.VEHICLE_ID
and vo.vehicle_ownerid =v.vehicle_ownerid  and trip_date >= date '2020-9-1' 
and trip_date <= date '2020-9-30'
group by  t.vehicle_ownerid)
union all
(select  'OCT' as month,t.vehicle_ownerid,(sum(t.total_payment))as total_income from trips t,vehicles v ,vehicle_owner vo
where 
 v.VEHICLE_ID =t.VEHICLE_ID
and vo.vehicle_ownerid =v.vehicle_ownerid  and trip_date >= date '2020-10-1' 
and trip_date <= date '2020-10-31'
group by  t.vehicle_ownerid)
union all
(select  'NOV' as month,t.vehicle_ownerid,(sum(t.total_payment))as total_income from trips t,vehicles v ,vehicle_owner vo
where 
 v.VEHICLE_ID =t.VEHICLE_ID
and vo.vehicle_ownerid =v.vehicle_ownerid  and trip_date >= date '2020-11-1' 
and trip_date <= date '2020-11-30'
group by  t.vehicle_ownerid)
union all
(select  'DEC' as month,t.vehicle_ownerid,(sum(t.total_payment))as total_income from trips t,vehicles v ,vehicle_owner vo
where 
 v.VEHICLE_ID =t.VEHICLE_ID`enter code here`
and vo.vehicle_ownerid =v.vehicle_ownerid  and trip_date >= date '2020-12-1' 
and trip_date <= date '2020-12-30'
group by  t.vehicle_ownerid);
```